# How to stop a timer at a certain value

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a timer that starts when you click a button. I want the timer to stop when the value of time reaches 5 but for some reason it isn't working.

```js
let words = document.getElementById("Words");
let wordAr = ["The" , "quick" , "brown" , "fox" , "jumped" , "over" , "the" , "lazy" , "dog"];
let textIn = document.getElementById("Input");
let timer = 0;
let time = document.getElementById("Timer");
let wPM = 0;
let wpm = document.getElementById("WPM");
let text = document.getElementById("text");

words.innerHTML = wordAr.slice(0,9).join(" ");

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(key){
 if(key.keyCode == 32){
  for (let i=0; i < 1; i++){
   wPM+=1;
   wpm.innerHTML = wPM; 
  };
 };
});

let start = document.getElementById("start");

function incTime(){
 timer++;
 time.innerHTML = timer;
}; 

function initTime(){
 setInterval(incTime, 1000);
};

if(timer == 5){
 console.log("done");
};
```

I've tried adding `.value` and using single equals and triple equals but all attempts are futile.

Comment: You should check `if(timer == 5)` inside `initTime()`

Comment: Not sure but should be If statement inside incTime function?

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work, I even tried refreshing the page!!

Comment: It works when I put it in `incTime` thanks guys

Comment: ya, it works when you put the check inside `incTime()` but because of the reason that you are using `setInterval()`, it will continue working after each seconds.

Comment: It doesn't work, the timer is still running, see the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

Add timer condition with in `incTime()` function.And use `clearInterval()` for break the `setInterval`

```js
var timer = 0;

function incTime() {
  timer++;
  console.log(timer);
  if (timer == 5) {
    clearInterval(time_int);
    console.log('breaked')
  };
};
var time_int = '';

function initTime() {
  time_int = setInterval(incTime, 1000);
};
initTime()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your case is if(timer == 5) check executes only once and doesn't check every time **timer** value is updated. You need to check **timer** value every time it is updated. by moving check inside **incTime()** update method

```js
let words = document.getElementById("Words");
let wordAr = ["The" , "quick" , "brown" , "fox" , "jumped" , "over" , "the" , "lazy" , "dog"];
let textIn = document.getElementById("Input");
let timer = 0;
let time = document.getElementById("Timer");
let wPM = 0;
let wpm = document.getElementById("WPM");
let text = document.getElementById("text");

words.innerHTML = wordAr.slice(0,9).join(" ");

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(key){
    if(key.keyCode == 32){
        for (let i=0; i < 1; i++){
            wPM+=1;
            wpm.innerHTML = wPM;    
        };
    };
});

let start = document.getElementById("start");

function incTime(){
    timer++;
    time.innerHTML = timer;
    if(timer == 5){
        console.log("done");
    }
};  

function initTime(){
    setInterval(incTime, 1000);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `clearInterval()` Method.

**In your case**:

```
let words = document.getElementById("Words");
let wordAr = ["The" , "quick" , "brown" , "fox" , "jumped" , "over" , "the" , "lazy" , "dog"];
let textIn = document.getElementById("Input");
let timer = 0;
let time = document.getElementById("Timer");
let wPM = 0;
let wpm = document.getElementById("WPM");
let text = document.getElementById("text");
let timerPid= null;

words.innerHTML = wordAr.slice(0,9).join(" ");

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(key){
    if(key.keyCode == 32){
        for (let i=0; i < 1; i++){
            wPM+=1;
            wpm.innerHTML = wPM;    
        };
    };
});

let start = document.getElementById("start");

function incTime(){
    timer++;
    time.innerHTML = timer;
};  

function initTime(){
    timerPid= setInterval(incTime, 1000);
};

if(timer == 5){
    clearInterval(timerPid);
};
```